# Copy a file from current folder to Installation folder while Installation -Install shield LE

Tags: c#, installshield

We are using "**Install Schield Limited Edition 2012**" to create the installer of  our application.
As per requirement we need to copy an xml file which is reside in  the set up folder to the installation folder. Is it possible?

For example:
Suppose our installer placed in “c:\NewFolder” and we will place the xml file to the same folder. When the user try to install the installer , we need to copy the xml file to the installation folder like c:\Programs\Application.
How can we accomplish this feature using Install schield limitted edition.

NS: We cannot embed the “XML” file with installer, since the xml content may change based on user

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks
Ranish

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, no installer will have a way to accomplish this. You best way would be to keep a batch file /vb script to run after installer and do the trick for you.

Comment: Can we achieve it through adding any type of classes like installer class?

Comment: There is no direct way but you can achieve it by the following, on app start , if the xml file is not found, download it from a static path (thinking you have a client-server architecture) where each user will have a different xml files

Comment: Is any other way to handle this.? From my resarch i found that need to set SourceDir property? How can i set this property from Install shield limited edition?